# Cordova tooling for IOS requires Apple macOS

Tags: cordova

I use Cordova on Windows and I added platform ios

```
$ cordova platform add ios
```

and now when I check

```
$ cordova requirements
```

I get error:

```
Cordova tooling for iOS requires Apple macOS
```

How to install Apple macOS on Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you will need to buy a mac computer or use a cloud service (such as [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/)) that builds your Cordova project on a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

> How to install Apple macOS on Windows 10 ?

You can only do that with emulators and cracked MacOS versions, but it's a waste of time because you cannot compile from Xcode then. Also, the second an update is available, you won't be able to install it.

To develop for iOS you need a **real Mac** (MacBook Air is now cheaper than an iPhone), or use PhoneGap Build (with its endless issues and limitations). And to submit your app to the Apple Store, the annual fee is 100 USD.